# Reality Capture API result availability after scene deletion

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-realitycapture

After the PhotoScene process is finished, there is available a time-limited HTTPS link to an output file of the specified format and [according to the documentation](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/reality-capture/v1/reference/http/photoscene-:photosceneid-GET/) it **will expire 7 days after the date of processing completion**.

But what will happen with scene results if the scene is deleted with `DELETE /photo-to-3d/v1/photoscene/:photosceneid`, are the results of processing also deleted, or still available for those 7 days?

Here is a typical `DELETE` request:

```
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/photoscene/abcd1234' \
  -X 'DELETE' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyjhbGCIOIjIuzI1NiISimtpZCI6'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By deleting the scene, you delete the resources associated to it (the ID, the uploaded images etc.) and consequently you cannot make new requests to it, like getting the results in another format.

However, the results that were already provided (the link to output file) are not part of the scene and will survive the scene deletion for the specified period.